# pip vendor certifi handle is invalid

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, terraform

The following may be due to the fact that I messed something regarding a SSL certificate up on my local machine? I encounter the issue during Terraform plan but maybe I need to reissue/install a certificate?

I use Visual Studio code in Windows and setup my AWS credentials/profile fine using the AWS CLI. I have this Main.tf file :

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-west-2"
    shared_config_files = ["C:\\Users\\blabla\\.aws\\config"]
    shared_credentials_files = ["C:\\Users\\blabla\\.aws\\credentials"]
    profile = "default"
}  

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
    bucket = "amazing-bucket"
}
```

I ran **terraform init** but after **terraform plan** I get:

```
│ Error:  Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: loading configuration: read C:\Users\blabla\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi: The handle is invalid.
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on Main.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
│    1: provider "aws" {
```

What does this mean? Is it related to an SSL certificate? It may be a Python related issue as pip appears in the error message?

When I run the above not as admin the error message contains the folder C:\data\ Where does it take these folder names from? It is just really odd.

Thanks!

PS:

When I run:

```
import certifi
print(certifi.where())
```

it points to this folder in the Terraform error message. Why is it looking there in the first place?!

PPS:

when I deliberately enter a wrong path for shared_config_files I get:

```
Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: failed to get shared config profile, default
```

This implies to me that shared_config_files points to the right place ...

Comment: From what I read in [their source code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/bf896df654b121a8066dc66087aea3df6ac8feaa/internal/conns/conns.go#L681), that error means that the AWS SDK wasn't successful in reading your credentials. Have you tested simply: `shared_credentials_files = "C:\Users\blabla\.aws\credentials"`?

Comment: Thanks will look tomorrow. Good idea to look in source ...

Comment: No that is not  the issue. why is it looking at C:\Users\blabla\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi anyway. It may have to do with ssl and connectivity to aws?

Comment: Which version of terraform are you on? And have you tried re-configuring your awscli credentials with `aws configure`?

Comment: Latest version just reinstalled today. And yes Aws configure worked. Can upload via python to existing S3 buckets  why on earth does it refer to these random paths/folders.i wonder

Comment: I don't know why they often give these cryptic error messages, but I've faced something similar and it turned out it was a parsing issue of the `credentials` file. Do you mind if I leave an official answer?